# Multiple INSERT/UPDATE on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-update

I have to perform a multiple insert/update using the ON DUPLICATE KEY instruction with one dynamic field and the others static. I've got the table "notifications" with fields:

```
ID (BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY), 
user (BIGINT UNIQUE), 
creator (BIGINT UNIQUE), 
type (TINYINT UNIQUE), 
value (BIGINT UNIQUE), 
date (INT), 
readed (TINYINT), 
erased (TINYINT).
```

I have to insert/update a row for each user (ID will be extracted by a query), so the value of the field "user" will be dynamic, the others are static. How I can perform this action with only one query on MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with procedures?

Comment: @Beri I usually don't use the procedures because my knowledge of them is very low, so I'm looking for a way using the traditional queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make use of PDO, you can build your query up and submit it once you've added all records.

Here's an example of using beginTransaction with commit.

This prepares your query, and then loops through a userlist and allocates each record.

After looping it commits/actions the query.

```
$dbc->beginTransaction();
$sql =  'INSERT INTO notifications (id,user,creator,type,value,date,readed,erased) '
    .   'VALUES (:id,:user,:creator,:type,:value,:date,:readed,:erased) '
    .   'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=:user ';

$sth= $dbc->prepare( $sql );


foreach( $userlist as $user )
{
    $sth->execute( array(
        ':id'=>$user['id'],
        ':user'=>$user['user'],
        ':creator'=>$user['creator'],
        ':type'=>$user['type'],
        ':value'=>$user['value'],
        ':date'=>$user['date'],
        ':readed'=>$user['readed'],
        ':erased'=>$user['erased']
     ));
}

$dbc->commit();
```

Some reference points:

- [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [PDO prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PDO Commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, I usually use PDO, this way will make only a query? The user value change at each insert, it will be extracted by a select query inside this insert query, all inserted fields will be updated on duplicate entry.

Comment: this way will act as 1 query, rather than looping your user list creating prepares and exec's 1000 times, as for the updating fields, in the example i am only updating the user field when its a duplicate entry, but you can easily change this to update multiple.. as a traditional update query would do :-)

Comment: Perfect, is possible to execute it more than 1000 times or this is the limit?

Comment: I just used 1000 as an example, I don't know of a limit, i guess the only way would be to try and see - it might be dependent on other settings like increasing your `max_execution_time`

Comment: @RyanJ if you think my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick to the left of it